# Why the sentence $(\exists x, y)(\neg x\equiv y)$ has at least 2 equivalence classes?

Tags: first-order-logic

$(\exists x, y)(\neg x\equiv y)$

In this case, I can only come up with the binary numbers $0$ and $1$. If not $0$, then must be $1$. Doesn't it has only 1 equivalence class?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a sentence having equivalence classes'?

Comment: @Bram28 The question in the textbook is Can you write down a sentence which states that there are at least two equivalence classes?

Comment: I'm confuse also. I didn't see an example to count the equivalence classes. I thought the equivalence classes are always infinity.

Comment: @yashirq There aren't always infinitely many equivalence classes. It depends on what set you're working with, and what the equivalence is. For example, consider an equivalence over $\mathbb R$ where $x \equiv y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Then there is only one equivalence class, although it has infinitely many elements. Or consider the set $A = \{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ and say that $x \equiv y$ if $x$ and $y$ have the same parity (i.e., even or odd). Then there are two equivalence classes, each with $5$ elements.

Comment: Good example for the even and odd. I'm a little bit more clear now. Thx. So for all integers mod 5, there are 5 equivalence classes, which are 0,1,2,3,4. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Do you see that the *numbers* $0,1,2,3,4$ are not the equivalence classes themselves, though, right? Equivalence classes are subsets of the given universe. We can call $[0]$ for example the set of all $x$ s.t. $x\equiv 0\text{ mod } 5$ and then it makes sense to say of those $x$'s that (i) $x\in[0]$ and (ii) $x\equiv 0$, for example. $[0]$ in this case is just a convenient name, we could've picked say, $A$ or $[10]$.